# LibreOffice Calc freezes with cpu usage at 33% when saving file (profile reset doesn't help)

Tags: libreoffice, cpu-load

That happens when saving in .xls. When saving in LibreOffice native format it just crashes without CPU usage, and when I reopen the file the changes have been not saved. In both cases I can't save new date to a file. Same happens with fresh blank file.

This started happening just today. Seems most people fix this by deleting their LibreOffice profile directory. Well, this doesn't help in my case.

So, what else I might try?

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned your Ubuntu version but I faced similar issue on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, with the pre-installed Libreoffice.

None of the resolutions suggested in other answers and forums worked.

So I uninstalled Libreoffice and installed the version where package source is "Canonical" and now the issue is resolved.

Edit 2018-05-05: I recall that the issue was with the "snap!"